# how to fit screen shot in to 800*600 bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, screenshot, scaling

i want to screen shot my screen and place it in 800*600 bitmap.
how can i do it?
the problem is that i can make a full 4K bitmap and then the whole screen shot will be inside and i cant do it otherwise.
and if the bit map is smaller it places only part of the screenshot.

```
  Bitmap bmpScreenCapture=new Bitmap(800,600);
       Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenCapture);
        //g.CopyFromScreen(800,
        //             600,
        //             0, 0,
        //             bmpScreenCapture.Size,
        //             CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        g.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                     Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                     0, 0,
                     bmpScreenCapture.Size,
                   CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
```

i am placing it eventually in a picture box

thanks 
very appriciate

Comment: If you mean copy from screen __and__ scale down you will have to do that in __two__ operations. There is a `DrawImage` overload that takes two rectangles, that will do the scaling..

Comment: `bmpScreenCapture` should be the size of the screen. Set picBox `SizeMode` to `StretchImage` and `picBox.Image = bmpScreenCapture;`

Comment: take a look at the Bitmap-Constructor `new Bitmap(screenshot, new Size(800,600));`. this creates a scaled bitmap (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wh0045z(v=vs.110).aspx )